# Domain of composite function

Tags: functions

Let g be a N → N function defined by

[image]

Not sure how to work out the domain of g(g(n)).

[image]

I got up to there on paper, and wrote out 5(5n), 5(6n), 6(5n), 6(6n). But I've no idea how the domain will work

Here's the solution
[image]

I understand the simplification on the right, but working out the domain originally is confusing me. It seems that the first "if" is relating to the outside function and then the second "if" is related to the function inside where n is subbed by 5n or 6n appropriately.

Would appreciate some clarification - is this a general rule of thumb?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: Yes, apologies forgot to mention this, will edit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way, The first time you apply the function, if $n>1$ then $6n >10$ when you apply the function again. You will have three possible cases. Numbers that stay less than $10$ after one iteration. Numbers that were less than $10$ after one time and are now greater than $10$. And then numbers that were already greater than $10$ the first time and are obviously greater the second. Does that help?

**Edit**

Yes, that solution is correct. Here is how they got there.

Say $0<n<1$

Then $g(n)= 6n$ and since $6n < 10$ we have $g(g(n)) = 36n$

Okay,  now do $2 < n < 10$.

We have $g(n)= 6n $ but this time  $6n > 10$ so when you use the formula again you multiply $6n$ by $5$ for $30n$

Finally, $n>10$.

Now, if $n>10$, then $5n>10$, so you have $5(5n)=25n$

If you look how they did the simplification in the solution they wrote down all possible sets of conditions. One of them could never happen $n>10$ with $5n<10$ so they removed it. Both conditions have to be true for it to be in that domain.

Comment: @ak1652 Did that help?